# Code for finding the maximum sum of a contiguous subarray fails a test case

Tags: c++, arrays, array-sum

Here is the problem - 
**Find the contiguous subarray within an array (containing at least one number) which has the largest sum.**

**For example:**

**Given the array [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],**

**the contiguous subarray [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.**

Here is my solution for this problem -

```
int Solution::maxSubArray(const vector<int> &A) {
int hi_sum = 0;
int cur_sum = 0;
int j = A.size() - 1;
int i = 0;

for(int k = 0; k<A.size(); k++)
{
    cur_sum += A[k];
}

hi_sum = cur_sum;

while(i != j)
{

        if(A[i] < A[j])
        {
            cur_sum -= A[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            cur_sum -= A[j];
            j--;
        }
    if(hi_sum < cur_sum) hi_sum = cur_sum;
    // cout<<"I - "<<i<<'\n'<<"J - "<<j<<'\n'<<"Sum - "<<hi_sum<<'\n'<<"Cur Sum - "<<cur_sum<<'\n';
}
return hi_sum;
}
```

And here is the test case for which my solution shows an output of 98 against the expectation of 217.

The first number '494' denotes the size.

```
494 
[ -120, -202, -293, -60, -261, -67, 10, 82, -334, -393, -428, -182, -138, -167, -465, -347, -39, -51, -61, -491, -216, -36, -281, -361, -271, -368, -122, -114, -53, -488, -327, -182, -221, -381, -431, -161, -59, -494, -406, -298, -268, -425, -88, -320, -371, -5, 36, 89, -194, -140, -278, -65, -38, -144, -407, -235, -426, -219, 62, -299, 1, -454, -247, -146, 24, 2, -59, -389, -77, -19, -311, 18, -442, -186, -334, 41, -84, 21, -100, 65, -491, 94, -346, -412, -371, 89, -56, -365, -249, -454, -226, -473, 91, -412, -30, -248, -36, -95, -395, -74, -432, 47, -259, -474, -409, -429, -215, -102, -63, 80, 65, 63, -452, -462, -449, 87, -319, -156, -82, 30, -102, 68, -472, -463, -212, -267, -302, -471, -245, -165, 43, -288, -379, -243, 35, -288, 62, 23, -444, -91, -24, -110, -28, -305, -81, -169, -348, -184, 79, -262, 13, -459, -345, 70, -24, -343, -308, -123, -310, -239, 83, -127, -482, -179, -11, -60, 35, -107, -389, -427, -210, -238, -184, 90, -211, -250, -147, -272, 43, -99, 87, -267, -270, -432, -272, -26, -327, -409, -353, -475, -210, -14, -145, -164, -300, -327, -138, -408, -421, -26, -375, -263, 7, -201, -22, -402, -241, 67, -334, -452, -367, -284, -95, -122, -444, -456, -152, 25, 21, 61, -320, -87, 98, 16, -124, -299, -415, -273, -200, -146, -437, -457, 75, 84, -233, -54, -292, -319, -99, -28, -97, -435, -479, -255, -234, -447, -157, 82, -450, 86, -478, -58, 9, -500, -87, 29, -286, -378, -466, 88, -366, -425, -38, -134, -184, 32, -13, -263, -371, -246, 33, -41, -192, -14, -311, -478, -374, -186, -353, -334, -265, -169, -418, 63, 77, 77, -197, -211, -276, -190, -68, -184, -185, -235, -31, -465, -297, -277, -456, -181, -219, -329, 40, -341, -476, 28, -313, -78, -165, -310, -496, -450, -318, -483, -22, -84, 83, -185, -140, -62, -114, -141, -189, -395, -63, -359, 26, -318, 86, -449, -419, -2, 81, -326, -339, -56, -123, 10, -463, 41, -458, -409, -314, -125, -495, -256, -388, 75, 40, -37, -449, -485, -487, -376, -262, 57, -321, -364, -246, -330, -36, -473, -482, -94, -63, -414, -159, -200, -13, -405, -268, -455, -293, -298, -416, -222, -207, -473, -377, -167, 56, -488, -447, -206, -215, -176, 76, -304, -163, -28, -210, -18, -484, 45, 10, 79, -441, -197, -16, -145, -422, -124, 79, -464, -60, -214, -457, -400, -36, 47, 8, -151, -489, -327, 85, -297, -395, -258, -31, -56, -500, -61, -18, -474, -426, -162, -79, 25, -361, -88, -241, -225, -367, -440, -200, 38, -248, -429, -284, -23, 19, -220, -105, -81, -269, -488, -204, -28, -138, 39, -389, 40, -263, -297, -400, -158, -310, -270, -107, -336, -164, 36, 11, -192, -359, -136, -230, -410, -66, 67, -396, -146, -158, -264, -13, -15, -425, 58, -25, -241, 85, -82, -49, -150, -37, -493, -284, -107, 93, -183, -60, -261, -310, -380 ]
```

Just paste it as it is.

I can't figure out the flaw in this solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your entire question.  Off-site links to questions are not appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Made the changes.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The entire question was added after this question was closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm) to solve this known problem in efficient way. Possible solution can be along the lines of:

```
int maxSubArraySum(const vector<int> &A) {
    int global_max = INT_MIN; 
    int max_at_position = 0;  

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        max_at_position = max_at_position + A[i];
        if (global_max < max_at_position){
            global_max = max_at_position;
        }

        if (max_at_position < 0) {
            max_at_position = 0;
        }
    }
    return global_max;
}
```

Comment: This [produces the expected result](https://www.ideone.com/zPOg3Y).

Comment: @DrewDormann +1 for the test.

Comment: @NiVeR Thanks for the solution. But my primary concern is to find the fault in the code I wrote.

Comment: @ANKURSATYA I think your solution is conceptually wrong.

Comment: I realized that and that is why I posted the question here. So that people can tell what is wrong.

Comment: @ANKURSATYA Conceptually wrong, means that your idea is wrong. Can't correct a wrong idea. You have to change it.

Comment: Thanks. Seriously, can you please point out the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173387/discussion-between-niver-and-ankur-satya).

Comment: I got the problem in my solution. To see the complete discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/8s7l1d/what_could_be_the_flaw_in_the_following_code_for/

Comment: So they basically said what i said, right? The idea is wrong.

Comment: Yes. But they also pointed out the mistake. That is the difference. Even I knew there was something wrong but it was not clear what was wrong neither to me nor to you, right?

Comment: I believe that the last sample that I send you was failing, no? Anyway if the problem is solved for you the discussion is over.